# How to fetch QTreeWidgetItem data?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to access an int value stored in my QTreeWidgetItem. This is what I'm currently trying, but it's not working.

```
void RecordWidget::recordWorkerStatusChanged(WorkerStatus status) {
    status.insertIntoTree(ui->treeWidget);
    qint64 qp = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(0)->child(2)->QTreeWidgetItem::data(0, Qt::UserRole).toInt();
}
```

The data I'm trying to access is the child at index 2, that is the avg bitrate. I want to access the value (QString::number((info.bytes*8*1000.0/info.currentTime)

```
 void insertIntoTree(QTreeWidget *tree) {
    tree->clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < streams.count(); i++) {
        quint64 key = streams.keys().at(i);
        const StreamInfo &info = streams.value(key);

        QTreeWidgetItem* parent = makeItem(StreamId::calcName(key), true);
        tree->addTopLevelItem(parent);
        parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("size %1 MB")).arg(QString::number(info.bytes/1000000.0, 'f', 2))));
        parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("duration %1")).arg(QDateTime::fromTime_t(info.currentTime/1000).toUTC().toString("HH:mm:ss"))));
        parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("avg bitrate %1 Mbit/s")).arg(QString::number((info.bytes*8*1000.0/info.currentTime)/1000000.0, 'f', 2))));
        parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("protocol %1")).arg(info.protocolName())));
        parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("bitrate mode %1")).arg(info.bitrateModeName())));
        parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("%1 TS/IP")).arg(info.tsPerIp)));
        if(info.networkJitters != 0){
            parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("%1 µs IAT deviation ")).arg(info.networkJitters)));
        }
        parent->addChild(makeItem(QString(tr("%1 PIDs")).arg(info.pidMap.size())));

        quint64 tsErrCount = info.tsErrors.totalErrors();
        QTreeWidgetItem* tserrors = makeItem(QString(tr("TsErrors (%1)")).arg(tsErrCount));
        parent->addChild(tserrors);
        if (tsErrCount > 0) tserrors->setExpanded(true);
        QMapIterator<TsErrors::ErrorType, qint64> it(info.tsErrors.errorCounter);
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            it.next();
            makeTsError(tserrors, it.value(), it.key());
        }

        parent->setExpanded(true);

        tree->clearSelection();
        parent->setSelected(true);
    }

}

};  


   QTreeWidgetItem* makeItem(QString text, bool parent = false) {
        QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList(text));
        item->setDisabled(!parent);
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown all the relevant code. I don't see where in this code you are using `QTreeWidgetItem::setData` with a `UserRole`, but you try to fetch data with the `UserRole`. You are just creating children with strings. What does `makeItem` do?

Comment: @replete I don't know what the purpouse of UserRole is tbh, it was a necessary parameter for the function data which should return some data from QTreeWidgetItem. It's just a possible solution I tried. I've included the makeItem method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTreeWidgetItem::data(0, Qt::UserRole)` fetches data set with `QTreeWidgetItem::setData(0, Qt::UserRole, yourData)`. You are creating items with formatted strings and expecting `QTreeWidgetItem::data` to recover the original data used to format those strings.  That is, after

```
QString(tr("avg bitrate %1 Mbit/s")).arg(QString::number((info.bytes*8*1000.0/info.currentTime)/1000000.0, 'f', 2))))
```

the calculated value is baked into the `QString`. You would need to parse the string, e.g. "avg bitrate 10 Mbit/s" to extract the value again.

Instead, consider passing the original data to your `makeItem` helper and do the string formatting there. This will enable `makeItem` to store the original data with `QTreeWidgetItem::setData`.

For example:

```
// Amend makeItem call as follows:
auto value = (info.bytes*8*1000.0/info.currentTime)/1000000.0;
parent->addChild(
    makeItem(QString(tr("avg bitrate %1 Mbit/s")).arg(QString::number(value, 'f', 2),
             value
));

// Amend makeItem as follows:        
QTreeWidgetItem* makeItem(QString text, QVariant value, bool parent = false) {
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList(text));
    item->setData(0, Qt::UserRole, value);
    item->setDisabled(!parent);
    return item;
}
```

Note that you can check `QVariant::toInt` conversion success:

```
// Amend:
qint64 qp = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(0)->child(2)->QTreeWidgetItem::data(0, Qt::UserRole).toInt();

// To:
auto item = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(0)->child(2);
auto itemData = item->QTreeWidgetItem::data(0, Qt::UserRole);
bool success;
qint64 qp = itemData.toLongLong(&success);
// Now you can check _success_ for whether the conversion worked.
```

Comment: This line does not give qp any value it seems i.e. the function call is neither returning a string nor int. qString qp = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(0)->child(2)->QTreeWidgetItem::data(0, Qt::UserRole).toInt();

Comment: Also, on which object should I call the QTreeWidgetItem::setData ? I'm confused about the column and role parameters required.

Comment: I tacked some code onto the answer to clarify what I meant, it's untested but should give you the right idea.